# Is it possible to customize Spring Cloud Data Flow dashboard/ admin user interface?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there a recommended way to customize the user interface of Spring Cloud Data Flow?

I am trying to find a way to change the text of the dashboard, colors and logos.

I found the GitHub repo for the UI on https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/

But I cannot understand how to integrate that with my backend because the APIs and docs are not provided. Neither style guides nor backend logic.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Cloud Data Flow UI is tightly coupled to the Spring Cloud Data Flow server (as one of the REST clients of the SCDF server) and hence it is not designed to be customizable or extensible. All the documentation we have for the SCDF UI is pertinent to the SCDF use cases only.